# How to find path of the user profile in VBA

Tags: windows, vba, path

How can I get the path of the current user that is as same as `%UserProfile%` result in Windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or, quite simply:

```
MsgBox Environ$("USERPROFILE")
```

---

You can use the `Environ()` method in VBA to expand environmental variables, just pass the argument as a string and drop the `%` markers.

Answer (score 0):

I use this function:

```
Private Declare Function GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowsDirectory Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetWindowsDirectoryA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, ByVal nSize As Long) As Long

' Return the user's profile path.
Private Function ProfilePath() As String
Dim win_dir As String
Dim user_name As String
Dim ret_len As Long

    ' Get the windows directory.
    win_dir = Space$(256)
    ret_len = GetWindowsDirectory(win_dir, Len(win_dir))
    win_dir = Left$(win_dir, ret_len)

    ' Get the user's name.
    user_name = Space$(256)
    GetUserName user_name, ret_len
    user_name = Left$(user_name, ret_len)

    If (Asc(Right$(user_name, 1)) = 0) Then
        user_name = Left$(user_name, Len(user_name) - 1)
    End If

    ProfilePath = win_dir & "\" & user_name
End Function
```

Comment: I am confused. If you have the solution, why is this a question? Or this code is part of the Question?

Comment: Absolutely, I was just curious as the asked was 8 minutes ago, and answered 8 minutes ago. Good. You could simply use `Environ("UserProfile")` too